# Convert named months date text to date

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a date text with named months like this

```
06:29 Mar. 17 2014
```

I tried this but obviously I need to convert `Mar` to a number

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(G1, 4) & "-" MID(G1,7,3) & "-" MID(G1,12,2))

Err:508
```

As this works

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(G1, 4) & "-03-" & MID(G1,12,2))
```

How to convert that text to a date?

Answer (score 0):

It works if I reformat it to `17-Mar-2014`

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(G1,12,2) & "-" & MID(G1,7,3) & "-" & RIGHT(G1, 4))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this statement:

> =DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(RIGHT(A1,4), "-", MID(A1,7,3), "-", MID(A1,12,2)))

or

> =DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,4) & "-" & MID(A1,7,3) & "-" & MID(A1,12,2))

Comment: How is that different from what I posted?

Comment: You were missing the second and fourth '&'.